# position of label box on qgis layout is not getting updating properly when updated from pyqgis

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

i am trying to update a layout by looping through layers and i have a label box next to lagend. i need to update the position of that box based on the updated width of the layout. here is what i came up with

```
layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName(ref_df['layout_name'][i])

for item in layout.items():
    if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemMap):
        if item.displayName() == 'Map 1':
            layer_names_to_map_item = common_layers
            layer_names_to_map_item[2] = ref_df['label_name'][i]
            
            layers_on_map = []
            for name in layer_names_to_map_item:
                layer = project.mapLayersByName(name)[0]
                if layer:
                    layers_on_map.append(layer)
                else:
                    print(f"{ref_df['label_name'][i]} does not exist to add to layout")
            
            item.setLayers(layers_on_map)

for item in layout.items():
    if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemLegend):
        if item.displayName() == '<Legend>':
            item.model().rootGroup().removeAllChildren()
            
            layer_names_to_add = layer_names_to_map_item[:len(layer_names_to_map_item)-1]
    
            for layer_name1 in layer_names_to_add:
                for layer_id, layer in project.mapLayers().items():
                    if layer.name() == layer_name1:
                                item.model().rootGroup().addLayer(layer)
            item.refresh()


for item in layout.items():
    if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemLegend):
        if item.displayName() == '<Legend>':
            legend_width = item.rect().width()
            offset = item.MapGridOffsetX

for item in layout.items():
    if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemLabel):
        if item.displayName() == 'Overall_Stats':
            layout_width = layout.width()
            box_width = item.rect().width()
            
            print(f"layout_width: {layout_width}")
            print(f"offset: {offset}")
            print(f"legend_width: {legend_width}")
            print(f"legend_width: {box_width}")
            print(f"Calculated X position: {layout_width - offset - legend_width - box_width}")
            item.setX(layout_width-offset-legend_width-box_width)
            item.refresh()
            
layout.refresh()

export_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
export_settings.dpi = 300
export_settings.exportDpi = True
export_settings.imageDpi = 300

image_output_path = os.path.join(plots_folder, f"{ref_df['label_name'][i]}.png")
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
result = exporter.exportToImage(image_output_path, export_settings)
```

it is working fine but the position of the box is not getting updated and as a result there is a gap between legend and label box. how to update the x position of the label box with respect legend properly?